# Get a single record from SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an `EditText` and I write on it the record which i want to appear in `TextView` after clicking on the Button

So I need retrieve a Row record from My DB and in specific Column 
and what I want to retrieve is String Type 
**This is My Query but it doest work with me **

```
 public String getCountryCode(String cc) {

 Cursor cursor = null;
 String Code = "";
 try{
     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE + " WHERE "
            + KEY_CODE + " = " + cc;
     cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


     if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

         cursor.moveToFirst();
         Code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_CODE"));
     }

     return Code;
 }finally {

     cursor.close();
 }
 }
```

**main activity**

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
String in   =codeinput.getText().toString();
String c    = dbHelper.getCountryCode(in);
CountryShow.setText(c);
}
catch(Exception e ){
    Toast.makeText(listViewDisplay.this, e.getMessage(),      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
});
```

Comment: I think problem with `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_CODE"));`. In getColumnIndex() parameter should be interger. @karim_mis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the query string with that

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE + " WHERE "
        + KEY_CODE + " = '" + cc+"'";
```

When you are going to add a generic value into your query string, you need to add single qouts around it

Comment: still not working , can I e-mail you and send for u the source code ?

Comment: @karim_mis just post all your code that you think it might be related, maybe someone else help with that and let me know

Comment: This does not work if the string value contains a quote.

Comment: @karim_mis The most likely reason is that that values does not exist in the database.

Comment: @karim_mis  double check what CL is saying to hardcoding the value CC with something you are 100% sure that it is exist in the Database

Comment: Good Idea , I entred some String which is suppose be in DB but stil not working , so i think the problem in my code

Comment: @karim_mis what is the error that you are getting ? try to print the exception in the `logcat` and let us know

Comment: Well , it works with me fine now :D All wat I need to clean my Data before start my App again <3

Comment: @karim_mis Good to hear that. Those things sometimes drive me crazy :D

Comment: @karim_mis you are welcome, don't forget to vote up the answer if you found it somehow useful ;)

Answer (score -1):

1. Try Change `cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);` to `cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{});`
2. I am not sure why you took KEY_CODE as a variable in `" WHERE " + KEY_CODE + " = " + cc;` you could change it to `" WHERE  KEY_CODE = " + cc;`
3. If type of `KEY_CODE` if it is string then change it to `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_CODE + " = '" + cc + "'";`

Comment: Is it returning any rows in cursor.getCount()?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           // get  the  data into array,or class variable
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
```